# Cannot call onActivityResult in fragment

Tags: android

There is a main class mainActivity. And fragments.

In one of the fragments google map. The feature is this:

When geolocation is turned off and the application is turned on, a request is sent to allow location detection and the onActivityResult method in the fragment should restart.

But the onActivityResult method only works in MainActivity when I give access to the location.

Please tell me how to fix this situation how to run the method in the fragment?
Thank you for your help!

**My attempts, but the method still does not work out:**

**Main Activity**

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
            fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

**MapFragment**

```
  // Get the current location of the device and set the position of the map.
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
   {
        if (requestCode == 51) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                getDeviceLocation();
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }
```

**UPDATE**

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    // Keys for storing activity state.
    private static final String KEY_CAMERA_POSITION = "camera_position";
    private static final String KEY_LOCATION = "location";

    // The entry point to the Fused Location Provider.
    private FusedLocationProviderClient _mFusedLocationProviderClient;

    private CameraPosition _mCameraPosition;

    // A default location (Минск, Беларусь) and default zoom to use when location permission is
    // not granted.
    private final LatLng mDefaultLocation = new LatLng(53.9000000, 27.5666700);
    private static final int DEFAULT_ZOOM = 17;

    private GoogleMap _map;

    // The geographical location where the device is currently located. That is, the last-known
    // location retrieved by the Fused Location Provider.
    private Location _mLastKnownLocation;
    private LocationCallback locationCallback;

    SharedManager _manager;
    Connect _connect;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        _manager = new SharedManager(getActivity());
        _connect = new Connect();


        // Construct a FusedLocationProviderClient.
        _mFusedLocationProviderClient = 
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());


        // Retrieve location and camera position from saved instance state.
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            _mLastKnownLocation = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_LOCATION);
            _mCameraPosition = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_CAMERA_POSITION);
        }

    }

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        //Инициализация карты
        initializeMap();


        return root;
    }

    /**
     * Saves the state of the map when the activity is paused.
     */
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        if (_map != null) {
            outState.putParcelable(KEY_CAMERA_POSITION, _map.getCameraPosition());
            outState.putParcelable(KEY_LOCATION, _mLastKnownLocation);
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        _map = googleMap;
        _map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
        _map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        updateLocationUI();

        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest);

        SettingsClient settingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(getActivity());
        Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = settingsClient.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());

        task.addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
                getDeviceLocation();
            }
        });

        task.addOnFailureListener(getActivity(), new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                if (e instanceof ResolvableApiException) {
                    ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                    try {
                        resolvable.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), 51);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Get the current location of the device and set the position of the map.
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        //TODO: код не отрабатывает, когда выключен локатор , после разрешения снова найти локацию
        if (requestCode == 51) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                getDeviceLocation();
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }

    /**
     * Gets the current location of the device, and positions the map's camera.
     */
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void getDeviceLocation() {
        /*
         * Get the best and most recent location of the device, which may be null in rare
         * cases when a location is not available.
         */
        try {
            Task<Location> locationResult = _mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
            locationResult.addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Set the map's camera position to the current location of the device.
                        _mLastKnownLocation = task.getResult();
                        if (_mLastKnownLocation != null) {
                            _map.moveCamera(
                                    CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                                            new LatLng(_mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(),
                                                    _mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), 15));
                        } else {
                            final LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
                            locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
                            locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
                            locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
                            locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                                    super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                                    if (locationResult == null) {
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    _mLastKnownLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                                    _map.moveCamera(
                                            CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                                                    new LatLng(_mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(),
                                                            _mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), 15));
                                    _mFusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
                                }
                            };
                            _mFusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null);

                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "unable to get last location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: %s", task.getException());
                        _map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                                .newLatLngZoom(mDefaultLocation, DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void updateLocationUI() {
        if (_map == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            {
                _map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                _map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    // Build the map.
    private void initializeMap() {
        if (_map == null) {
            SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_View);
            mapFrag.getMapAsync(MapFragment.this);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: show us the code for "a request is sent to allow location detection"

Comment: Why don't you start the request from the fragment and get the result back to the same fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` below because it's call super method first.

**Main Activity**

```
YourFragment yourFragment = new YourFragment(); //And use this object to all over

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == YOUR_FRAGMENT_CODE) {
        try {
            yourFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); //Add Here
}
```

I hope this can help you!

Comment: For some reason, it does not work out. when executed does not even go to the method

Comment: What is issue generated?

Comment: @Geferson So need to manage as per updated answer because in your case not getting fragment So,it's gave this error.Please check updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I started calling the method, but it throws an exception when I try to find the location:  .location.FusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation()' on a null object reference

Comment: @Geferson It's is error of when you are getting location.please share your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207756/discussion-between-geferson-and-hardik-talaviya).