# Pass activity result to correct fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have several fragments in view pager. Some of them can trigger the method to attach some file or take a photo. Currently from the fragment I am calling method from activity to get a file (file picker intent) or taking photo (camera intent), process it in onActivityResult and would like to deliver this file to the proper fragment but sometimes it shows like the visible fragment is different than should be. I wanted to have it in one place instead of onActivityResult in each fragment that's why i wanted to put it to the activity. Is that a correct way or how can I do that correctly?

To clarify I want to pass new Object created inside the onActivityResult to show something in the fragment recycler view.

I am using below code to check the visible fragment:

```
private Fragment getVisibleFragment() {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = MyActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
        List<Fragment> fragments = fragmentManager.getFragments();
        for (Fragment fragment : fragments) {
            if (fragment != null && fragment.isVisible())
                return fragment;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60206061/11158194 link may be it's helpful for you.

Comment: "Some of them can trigger the method ..." why don't your activity remember somehow which fragment called the method, and then passed result to it?

Comment: @Hardik the problem is, I have several different fragments dynamically created and don't know which one is currently visible.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me; in my app I upload multiple photos to the server,
 selecting photos from gallery in fragment and pass result activity to
 fragment.

```
 GallaryFragment mFragment = new GallaryFragment(); 

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == YOUR_FRAGMENT_CODE) {
        try {
            //Your Selected Data From Gallery
            mFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 }
```

Comment: The problem is, I have several different fragments dynamically created and don't know which one is currently visible.

Comment: make fragment object globally and use like a above example