# Permission dialog not appearing in fragment

Tags: android, android-permissions

I want to request a permission from the user which is SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission, for running my activities in the background or when the app isn't running. I'm using a fragment, where I'm asking for permissions.

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW},SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW_CODE);
            requestPermissions(new  String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},123);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"OK",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

the strange thing is that, The toast which is there within if block is executed but the dialog does not appears. 
here's my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.raunak.alarmdemo4">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60206061/11158194 may be it's helpful for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SYSTEM\_ALERT\_WINDOW - How to get this permission automatically on Android 6.0 and targetSdkVersion 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016369/system-alert-window-how-to-get-this-permission-automatically-on-android-6-0-an)